# set default parameter for where condition in sql

Tags: mysql, sql, null

I need to use a default if the value is null in sql where condition as below.

```
SELECT sla.incident_generated_sla from eventedge_events_sla sla where e.client_id=sla.client_id and sla.priority_id=e.priority_id
```

I used below query but not working.

```
(SELECT sla.incident_generated_sla from eventedge_events_sla sla where e.client_id=sla.client_id and sla.priority_id=(IsNull(e.priority_id,"2")))
```

Comment: tag the DBMS (MySQL, MS SQL Server, etc...) which u r using.

Comment: `COALESCE`? https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT sla.incident_generated_sla from eventedge_events_sla sla 
where e.client_id=sla.client_id and sla.priority_id=e.priority_id

(SELECT sla.incident_generated_sla from eventedge_events_sla sla 
where e.client_id=sla.client_id and sla.priority_id=(IsNull(e.priority_id,"2")))
```

You've almost made it.

Check this correction to your own try:

```
SELECT sla.incident_generated_sla from eventedge_events_sla sla 
    where e.client_id=sla.client_id and sla.priority_id=ISNULL(e.priority_id,2)
```

Now I don't know what your "e" is, but if this is declared with the client_id you're looking for, it should work.

Take a closer look at my correction to your ISNULL.

EDIT: After comments this answer is the correct;

```
SELECT
    e.event_start_time,
    sla.incident_generated_sla

FROM
    eventedge_events_sla sla
    left outer join eventedge_events e 
    ON  e.client_id = sla.client_id 
        AND isnull(e.priority_id,2) = sla.priority_id
```

Comment: Otherwise it looks like you haven't declared your "e". - You can do this with an INNER JOIN. Let me know your tablename that "e" should be declared to, and I'll edit the answer for you.

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '2) LIMIT 0, 30' at line 2

Comment: SELECT e.event_start_time, (SELECT sla.incident_generated_sla from eventedge_events_sla sla where e.client_id=sla.client_id and sla.priority_id=e.priority_id) as sla FROM `eventedge_tickets` t, `eventedge_events` e

Answer (score 0):

It's [IFNULL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/control-flow-functions.html) if it's MySQL.

```
SELECT sla.incident_generated_sla 
FROM eventedge_events_sla sla 
    LEFT JOIN eventedge_events e ON e.client_id = sla.client_id 
WHERE sla.priority_id = IFNULL(e.priority_id,"2");
```